# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' latest-ami.py

Tags: python

how to fix the below error

```
[system@root selectami]$ python latest-ami.py eu-west-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "latest-ami.py", line 60, in <module>
    print(source_image['ImageId'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
[system@root selectami]$
```

## the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3
import sys

from dateutil import parser

region = sys.argv[1]

def newest_image(list_of_images):
    latest = None

    for image in list_of_images:
        if not latest:
            latest = image
            continue

        if parser.parse(image['CreationDate']) > parser.parse(latest['CreationDate']):
            latest = image

    return latest

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

filters = [ {
        'Name': 'name',
        'Values': ['amzn-ami-hvm-*']
    },{
        'Name': 'description',
        'Values': ['Amazon Linux AMI*']
    },{
        'Name': 'architecture',
        'Values': ['x86_64']
    },{
        'Name': 'owner-alias',
        'Values': ['amazon']
    },{
        'Name': 'owner-id',
        'Values': ['137112412989']
    },{
        'Name': 'state',
        'Values': ['available']
    },{
        'Name': 'root-device-type',
        'Values': ['ebs']
    },{
        'Name': 'virtualization-type',
        'Values': ['hvm']
    },{
        'Name': 'hypervisor',
        'Values': ['xen']
    },{
        'Name': 'image-type',
        'Values': ['machine']
    } ]

response = client.describe_images(Owners=['amazon'], Filters=filters)

source_image = newest_image(response['Images'])
print(source_image['ImageId'])
```

Comment: Fix indentation

Comment: Can you `print(source_image)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source_image` is `None`, therefore `newest_image(response['Images'])` is `None` therefore `list_of_images` has no `image` that is `False` and no `image` such that `parser.parse(image['CreationDate']) > parser.parse(latest['CreationDate'])` is true.

You could change `newest_image` to raise an error on no new image found instead of returning `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `newest_image` seems to return `None`, so, your `print` calls `None['ImageId']`, and that's where you get the error. Check that the `response['Images']` is not an empty list, and, if it is, change the filters appropriately so that you get some valid  return value

Answer (score 0):

In the function here -

```
def newest_image(list_of_images): # list_of_images is passed here, which in your case is []
    latest = None # latest is set to None here
    # Since list_of_images is empty, this for loop does not work
    for image in list_of_images: 
        if not latest:
            latest = image
            continue

        if parser.parse(image['CreationDate']) > parser.parse(latest['CreationDate']):
            latest = image
    # since for loop did not run, latest still is None
    return latest
```

The reason why you get this error is because `newest_image` returned `None` and therefore `source_image` is None and by this -

```
print(source_image['ImageId'])
```

And you are trying to **get an item** out of `None`, therefore -

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

You could handle it like -

```
try:
    print(source_image['ImageId'])
except TypeError:
    print("Oops! Returned None")
```

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: If `response` was empty then `response["Images"]` would raise a `KeyError`. It's obviously `response["Images"]` which is empty.

Comment: You got me thinking, response must be `None` that's why error says `NoneType`, if it were empty, it would have been `KeyError` @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: please re-read the traceback more carefully - the error happens here : `print(source_image['ImageId'])` - not when trying to access `response["Images"]`.

Comment: Thanks all, I was under the impression that 'response["Images"]' will get a value from the filter criteria..  what would be the correct way of syntax ?

Comment: Can you print `response` @m.jack?

Comment: response = client.describe_images(Owners=['amazon'], Filters=filters)

    source_image = newest_image(response['Images'])

    print(source_image['ImageId'])
    except TypeError:
        print("Oops! Returned None")
    [system@root selectami]$ python latest-ami.py us-west-1
      File "latest-ami.py", line 62
        except TypeError:
             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    [system@root selectami]$

Comment: You are asking the syntax for?

Comment: yeah.. like what would be the right format for the below:

Comment: `response = client.describe_images(Owners=['amazon'], Filters=filters)`  

`source_image = newest_image(response['Images'])`  

`print(source_image['ImageId'])`

Comment: Just do `print(source_image)` and `print(response)`. One of the two will have None in it. Do post what gets printed

Comment: did that, `[system@root selectami]$ python latest-ami.py us-west-1`  
'None'
'{u'Images': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'df6de904-1536-4002-b458-d9526c9e84f9', 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Tue, 24 Jul 2018 13:38:09 GMT', 'content-length': '219', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}}}`'

Comment: @m.jack I'll edit my answer, It'll make it clearer to you what's happening in your code

Comment: The output should be the image ID like in [link](https://github.com/bwood/latest-ami)

Comment: print(source_image) throws out `None`

Comment: `print(response)` throws out `{u'Images': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '1bc6cc41-d4d8-45f1-b176-24ac13ab90ff', 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Tue, 24 Jul 2018 13:45:14 GMT', 'content-length': '219', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}}}`

Comment: perfect, understood.. Thanks @ThatBird